# Does there exists this kind of real sequence?

Tags: calculus

Does the sequence $(a_n)$ with the following properties exists?

- $(a_n)$ converges to $a$.
- $(a_n)$ is strictly increasing.
- $(a_n)$ is not bounded by $\max\{a_1, a\}$.

Also, I need to find a sequence $(b_n)$ such that $(\frac {1}{n})$ and $(\frac {-1}{n})$ are subsequences of $(b_n)$, but $(b_n)$ is unbounded.

I have been trying to find examples, but nothing useful  comes to my mind. Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance
Cheers

Comment: What does it mean to be bounded by $\max\{a_1,a\}$ in case they are both negative?

Comment: Bounded means $\left| a_n \right| \leqslant \max\{a_1,a\}$

Comment: Ok, in that case you accepted an answer that does not answer the question.

Comment: What happens is that the question is fully answered in two different answers

Comment: Well, you asked **two** questions in one, causing this mess. Next time, please do not do that.

Comment: Given your definition of bounded here, all you need is some strictly increasing sequence that converges to $a$ with $a_1< -|a|$, and then $a_1$ will not be bounded by that definition, since $|a_1| > a$ and $|a_1|>a_1$. It should be noted that bounded is often used in both directions, as $|a_n| \le \max(|a_1|,|a|)$ for all $n$,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $(a_n)$ is strictly increasing with limit $a$, then you have $a_1\leq a_n<a$, **no matter what**. Obviously, this sequence is bounded by $\max\{|a_1|, |a|\}$.

If this is what you mean by $\max\{a_1,a\}$, then the answer is NO, such sequence does not exist. If you mean something different by that, like that $|a_n|\leq\max\{a_1,a\}$, then a sequence $a_1=-100$ and $a_n=1-1/n$ for $n\geq2$ seems to be what you are looking for.

We can actually go further and take the sequence $a_n=-1/n$, it's increasing and converging to $a=0$, and no element satistfies $|a_n|<\max\{a_n,a\}=0$.

---

For your 2nd question, take any shuffle (interleave) of the sequences $(1/n)$, $(-1/n)$ and $(n)$ or any other unbounded sequence, and it will satisfy your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

If a function is strictly increasing and converges, then its limit is necessarily an upper bound.

Comment: I really wonder who have downvoted both my and your answer without leaving a comment, and **why** he has done so.

Comment: Somebody who does not understand how limits work maybe?

Comment: Soomebody who dislikes increasing sequences:)

Comment: To add to the answer, the limit is equal to $\sup \{a_n\}$ in such case.

Answer (score 2):

First question: no. If $(a_n)$ is strictly increasing, and converges to $a$, then $\forall n$, $(a_n)< a$. Which you can show by "Reductio ad absurdum". Since $a_1 < a$, $\max\{a_1,a\} =a$ (strange condition), $(a_n)$ is boounded by $a$, no question.

Second question: write it modulo $3$: $k = 3n+m$, $0\le m \le 2$. Then define, for  $k> 2$:

- $b_k = {n}$ if $m = 0$,
- $b_k = \frac{1}{n}$ if $m = 1$,
- $b_k = -\frac{1}{n}$ if $m = 2$,
- and if you want $b_0 = b_1=b_2 = 0$ to avoid troubles at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question also